# Узнать id по нажатию jQuery

Tags: jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sub_m4").click(function () {
      $("#Subtable4").fadeToggle();
   
  });
  $(fadeout).click(function () {
    $("#sub_m4").fadeOut();
   
  });
  $(fadein).click(function () {
    $("#sub_m4").fadeIn();
   
  });


});
```

```css
table{
 border:2px solid grey;
}
th{
 width:30%;
}
tr{
 width:100%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
table tr{
 text-align: center;
}
.dws-menu *{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
.dws-menu tr [type="checkbox"]{
 display: none;
}
 
.dws-menu label.toogleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d7";
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dws-menu input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}    
.dws-menu input.toogleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toogleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#Subtable4 {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
}
#Stip{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
#Subtable p{
  border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

#Kopmitne{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.text{
 width: 100%;
 border-left:1px solid grey;
}

.table_row {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
#tdd{
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 border-top:4px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabula.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/menu.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/320ac68418.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

<nav class="dws-menu">  
 <table width="100%" id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th_width">###</th>
      <th class="th_width">###</th>
      <th class="th_width">###</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
 <tr>
     <td>##</td>
     <td>###</td></td>
     <td>### </td>

     <td id="check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" id="sub_m4">
      <label for="sub_m4" class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="table_row">
   <td id="tdd">
       <div  id="Subtable4">
        <div id="Stip">
         <p>Stip
         <span class="text">Jjjj</span></p>
     </div>
     <div id="Kop">
         <p >Kop
         <span class="text">Jjjj</span></p>
        </div>
       </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody> 
  </table>
</nav>

 




















</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/320ac68418.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">
<header>


<nav class="dws-menu">  
    <table width="100%" id="table">
    <thead>
       <tr>
            <th class="th_width">№№</th>
            <th class="th_width">№№</th>
            <th class="th_width">№№</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td>SSS</td>
        <td>SSS</td></td>
        <td>SSS</td>

        <td id="check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" id="sub_m4">
            <label for="sub_m4" class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td id="tdd">
                <div  id="Subtable4">
                    <div id="Stip">
                        <p>Stip
                        <span class="text">##</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="Kop">
                        <p >Kop
                        <span class="text">##</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
    </table>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<tr>
        <td>###</td>
        <td>###</td></td>
        <td>### </td>

        <td id="check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" id="#sub_m4">

            <label for="sub_m4" class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td id="tdd">
                <div  id="#Subtable4">
                    <div class="Myclass"id="###">
                        <p>S
                        <span class="text">jjj</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="#####">
                        <p >Kkk
                        <span class="text">jjjj</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

вот

```
  <tr>
        <td>ttt</td>
        <td>ttt</td></td>
        <td>ttt</td>

        <td id="check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" 
id='.$id.'>

            <label for='.$id.' class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="table_row">
            <td id="tdd">
                <div  id='.$id_subT.'>
                    <div class="ClasNAME"id="###">
                        <p>sss
                        <span class="text">ppp</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="$$$">
                        <p >KKKK
                        <span class="text">ppp</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

нажимаю на input и должна появляется невидимая часть id_SUbT. надо прочитать id label (оно с input одинаково ) и потом прочитать id .$id_subT. и вывести...
Если запись одна то не трудно , а если их много , то надо как то читать id по нажатию , я думал each функцию попробовать ,но у меня нечего не выходит , пожалуйста, помогите .

'.$id.'=#sub_m4
'.$id_subT.'=#Subtable4

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sub_m4").click(function () {
      $("#Subtable4").fadeToggle();

  });
  $(fadeout).click(function () {
    $("#sub_m4").fadeOut();

  });
  $(fadein).click(function () {
    $("#sub_m4").fadeIn();

  });


});
```

Comment: нижний кусок кода это, если бы была бы одна запись, а так их тысячи к примеру и я не знаю как получить эти два id после нажатия

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: крч есть таблица , в ней есть блоки , которые скрыты. нажимаю на стрелочку(лэйбл ) и появляется блок , нажимаю обратно он закрывается. Если одна запись в таблице(одна строчка), то ок (кусок кода) , а если этих строчек 1к?  то надо получить id лэйбла и id дива <div  id='.$id_subT.'>

Comment: Создайте в вопросе пример html-а такой таблицы - без фрагментов php.

Comment: создал....наверху

Comment: Вы на сайте - пять месяцев. В редакторе вопроса есть инструмент для создания работающего фрагмента HTML/JS/CSS.

Comment: сделал(раньше не умел , так как редко захожу) но jquery не смог вставить , но так оно работает , в если 10000  записей то тогда надо читать id лэйбла и div id  subtable по нажатию , я не знаю как ...можно как то через функцию each , но я не знаю как эти два ид взять

Comment: @СаскеУчиха, хотел поправить вопрос.. Но ничего не понял, когда пытался собрать код в сниппет..
Добавьте, пожуйста, скриншот того, что должно получиться, я напишу код.

Comment: поставил изображение наверху ...есть таблица, она закрыта и нажимая на стрелочку , появляется блок div id="Subtable" с содержанием vvvv. если он один такой , то нормально , а если их 100000000000000 , то я включаю php и гинирирую новое ид для лэйбла и новое для div id=Subtable...sub_m1 Subtable1 , sub_m2 Subtable2  и тд. и тип после нажатия на стрелочку он должен прочитать ид лэйбла и ид div subtable чтоб вставить в jquery код и вывести . повторюсь, что с одной строчкой проблем нет , а вот когда их 2+ то это конец ...говорили each заюзать, но я не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите сделать что-то такое. Но не совсем ясно что должно быть в итоге.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input.toogleSubmenu").click(function () {
   $("#Subtable"+$(this).prop("id").substr(5)).fadeToggle();
   
  });
});
```

```css
table{
 border:2px solid grey;
}
th{
 width:30%;
}
tr{
 width:100%;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
table tr{
 text-align: center;
}
.dws-menu *{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
.dws-menu tr [type="checkbox"]{
 display: none;
}
 
.dws-menu label.toogleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d7";
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dws-menu input.toggleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toggleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}    
.dws-menu input.toogleSubmenu:checked ~ label.toogleSubmenu .fa::before{
  content: "\f0d8";
  color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#tdd>div {
 width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
#Stip{
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
#Subtable p{
  border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}

#Kopmitne{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.text{
 width: 100%;
 border-left:1px solid grey;
}

.table_row {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 300%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
#tdd{

 width: 100%;
 border-top:4px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tabula.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/menu.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/320ac68418.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

<nav class="dws-menu">  
 <table width="100%" id="table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th_width">a</th>
      <th class="th_width">b</th>
      <th class="th_width">c</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody> 
 <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td></td>
     <td>3</td>

     <td id="check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" id="sub_m1">
      <label for="sub_m1" class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td></td>
     <td>6</td>

     <td id="check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="toogle"  class="toogleSubmenu" id="sub_m2">
      <label for="sub_m2" class="toogleSubmenu"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="table_row">
   <td id="tdd">
       <div id="Subtable1">12345</div>
     <div id="Subtable2">ghty</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody> 
  </table>
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: да да да , почти , только у меня скрытый блок выезжает сразу под строчкой где стрелочка ,и потом под этим блоком строчки продолжаются, а у вас под таблицей.... и вы перекопировали дважды , а я хочу,  чтоб  sub_m и subtable создавалось поновой с циклом фор (php код , там написано) и потом уже нажимая они появлялись

Comment: Ну тогда даже лучше. Кот тоже работать будет. Только tdd добавить если надо скрывать показывать. Я у себя не стал скрывать.

Comment: у вас вот написать Substable ,  а мне тогда что писать , если я юзаю <div  id='.$id_subT.'> ?

Comment: По моему это переменная php кода. Вы должны понимать что у вас получится там в итоге.

Comment: да , я понимаю , что в итоге будет Substable1 Substable2 Substable3 и тд , но вот тогда ваш метод не работает(((((((((((((((.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
  $("input.toogleSubmenu").click(function () {
   $("#Subtable"+$(this).prop("id").substr(5)).fadeToggle();
   
  });
});

Comment: Вы наверно забыли tdd показать. Неужели так сложно в просмотре кода глянуть что не срабатывает?

Comment: Нужно добавить что то вроде $("#Subtable"+$(this).prop("id").substr(5)).parent().fadeToggle();

Comment: спасибо , спасибо , спасибо , спасибо Вам большое , спасибо , спасибо , спасибо , спасибо. просто влез туда, где не понимаю так как горит и надо сделать...спасибо спасибо спасибо спасибо. 1000000 раз спасибо большое . спасибо

Comment: @СаскеУчиха если ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как `правильный` галочкой слева

Answer (score 0):

По нажатию на элемент в таблице получаешь его id, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

```js
//$("td.group").click(function(){
//  alert("id товара:" + $(this).parent().find("td:first").attr("class").replace("product_","") + "; " + //$(this).text());
//});
//$("td[class *= product_]").click(function(){
//  alert("id товара:" + $(this).attr("class").replace("product_",""));
//});
$("td[class*=product_]").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find(".btn").toggle("slow",()=> {});
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Название</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="product_1">Товар 1</td>
      <td class="group">Группа 1</td>
      <td class="btn"><button>TEST</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="product_2">Товар 2</td>
      <td class="group">Группа 1</td>
      <td class="btn"><button>TEST</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="product_3">Товар 3</td>
      <td class="group">Группа 2</td>
      <td class="btn"><button>TEST</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ок, а как мне тогда прочитать и id лэйбла и потом еще id дива где subtable ?так как он то  и скрыт ...так как subtable скрыт и мы нажимаем на стрелочку(лабел) и он появляется 
п.с. там есть наверху jq код , который здесь не запускается (не умею), а так он работает . вот как мне вставить за место sub_m4 и за место Subtable  то два ид , которое я узнаю при нажатии

Comment: вам в этом помогут ментоды `.parent()`, `.childs()`, `.find()`, `.each()`

Comment: вот   each  я как раз пробовал , но не выходит

Comment: @СаскеУчиха обновил ответ

Comment: у вас по нажатию на одно и на второе, а мне надо было бы , где я нажимаю на sub_m1 и там уже узнается id Subtable не нажимая по нему... он скрыт. я узнаю id (ну допустим узнал )sub_m1 и нажал и выехал блок subtable(посмотрите мой jquery код наверху)...

Comment: @СаскеУчиха Вы хотите, чтобы у вас после нажатия на ячейку что-то выезжало?? например доп инфа какая то или ссылки?

Comment: @СаскеУчиха Вам легче нарисовать чего вы хотите...а то вообще не понятно

Comment: да, выезжала инфа , которая стоит в классе table row ->td id="tdd"->и вот самый главный див div id=subtable4 вот он должен выезжать как я нажму на стрелочку( label) sub_4 ...  можете html код увидеть наверху вместе с php. если одна строчка то не проблема, а если их много(php) то я не знаю

Comment: @СаскеУчиха снова изменил...посмотрите (нажмите на товар)

Comment: спасибо за помощь))))